# Проблема с сортировкой списка

Tags: python

подскажите в чем проблема. Есть папка с файлами
F_1.jpg, F_2.jpg, F_3.jpg ... и т.д. более ста тыщ по порядку.
Делаю список

```
b = [i for i in os.listdir(path='C:/Users/vovad/Desktop/Screen/Screenshots/')]
```

Далее делаю сортировку

```
b.sort()
```

Получаю вот такую фигню вообще не по порядку. В чем может быть проблема?

```
'F_0.jpg',
 'F_1.jpg',
 'F_10.jpg',
 'F_100.jpg',
 'F_1000.jpg',
 'F_10000.jpg',
 'F_100000.jpg',
 'F_100001.jpg',
 'F_100002.jpg',
 'F_100003.jpg',
 'F_100004.jpg',
 'F_100005.jpg',
 'F_100006.jpg',
 'F_100007.jpg',
 'F_100008.jpg',
 'F_100009.jpg',
 'F_10001.jpg',
 'F_100010.jpg',
 'F_100011.jpg',
 'F_100012.jpg',
 'F_100013.jpg',
 'F_100014.jpg',
 'F_100015.jpg',
 'F_100016.jpg',
 'F_100017.jpg',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что у вас строки и сортировка идет по правилам сравнения строк (лексиграфически)

вам надо извлечь число из имени файла и уже сравнивать числа

хотите сравнивать числа - можно сделать так:

```
import re
arr.sort(key=lambda name: int(re.findall("\d+", name)[0]))
```

простой код, не учитывающий, что в имени может не быть чисел или быть несколько чисел, но модифицировать для этих случаев вы можете сами

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 4):

Есть же специальный модуль для "натуральной сортировки" - [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/). Вроде бы он ваш случай правильно понимает:

```
from natsort import natsorted

lst = [
 'F_0.jpg',
 'F_1.jpg',
 'F_10.jpg',
 'F_100.jpg',
 'F_1000.jpg',
 'F_10000.jpg',
 'F_100000.jpg',
 'F_100001.jpg',
 'F_100002.jpg',
 'F_100003.jpg',
 'F_100004.jpg',
 'F_100005.jpg',
 'F_100006.jpg',
 'F_100007.jpg',
 'F_100008.jpg',
 'F_100009.jpg',
 'F_10001.jpg',
 'F_100010.jpg',
 'F_100011.jpg',
 'F_100012.jpg',
 'F_100013.jpg',
 'F_100014.jpg',
 'F_100015.jpg',
 'F_100016.jpg',
 'F_100017.jpg',
]

print(*natsorted(lst), sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
F_0.jpg
F_1.jpg
F_10.jpg
F_100.jpg
F_1000.jpg
F_10000.jpg
F_10001.jpg
F_100000.jpg
F_100001.jpg
F_100002.jpg
F_100003.jpg
F_100004.jpg
F_100005.jpg
F_100006.jpg
F_100007.jpg
F_100008.jpg
F_100009.jpg
F_100010.jpg
F_100011.jpg
F_100012.jpg
F_100013.jpg
F_100014.jpg
F_100015.jpg
F_100016.jpg
F_100017.jpg
```

Comment: Этот модуль все случаи правильно понимает.

Answer (score 3):

Я когда-то отдельно занимался этой задачей. [Natural sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) удивительно сложно устроен если нужно поддержать разные текстовые префиксы, инфиксы и суффиксы. В числах могут быть лидирующие нули, которые тоже нужно различать. Ниже приведено корректное с моей точки решение. Оно несколько расточительно, но работает. Идея в том чтобы все не цифры заменить на пары `(<символ>, 0)`, а все цифровые последовательности на пары `('0', <число>)`. Все такие пары сравнимы. Все числа располагаются среди других символов там же где цифры. Все числа между собой сравниваются правильно. Лидирующие нули в числах упорядочены определённым образом:

```
import re


def natsort_key(s):

    def parts():
        for t in re.finditer('[1-9][0-9]*|.', s):
            t = t.group(0)
            if t.isdigit():
                yield '0', int(t)
            else:
                yield t, 0

    return tuple(parts())


a = (
    'F_0.jpg', 'F_1.jpg', 'F_10.jpg', 'F_100.jpg', 'F_1000.jpg', 'F_10000.jpg',
    'F_100000.jpg', 'F_100001.jpg', 'F_100002.jpg', 'F_100003.jpg',
    'F_100004.jpg', 'F_100005.jpg', 'F_100006.jpg', 'F_100007.jpg',
    'F_100008.jpg', 'F_100009.jpg', 'F_10001.jpg', 'F_100010.jpg',
    'F_100011.jpg', 'F_100012.jpg', 'F_100013.jpg', 'F_100014.jpg',
    'F_100015.jpg', 'F_100016.jpg', 'F_100017.jpg'
)
print(*sorted(a, key=natsort_key), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ python natsort.py
> F_0.jpg
> F_1.jpg
> F_10.jpg
> F_100.jpg
> F_1000.jpg
> F_10000.jpg
> F_10001.jpg
> F_100000.jpg
> F_100001.jpg
> F_100002.jpg
> F_100003.jpg
> F_100004.jpg
> F_100005.jpg
> F_100006.jpg
> F_100007.jpg
> F_100008.jpg
> F_100009.jpg
> F_100010.jpg
> F_100011.jpg
> F_100012.jpg
> F_100013.jpg
> F_100014.jpg
> F_100015.jpg
> F_100016.jpg
> F_100017.jpg
> ```